# (Android 11) How do I allow an app to access a file in another app's Android/data folder?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-11

I have two apps. One app (P) consumes a file with a proprietary extension (say .XXX) and a .json file with instructions for what P will be doing with that other file. The other app (Q) creates those files and intents to P, telling P the path to the .json file, which contains the path to the .XXX file. P then reads the .json file (in Q's directory) and then reads the .XXX file (again, in Q's directory). P does a lot of stuff with the .XXX file, but I don't believe P has to write to it.

Prior to Android 11, all the files were just in root/MyAppDirectory_Q and it was easy to access/share files between apps. With scoped storage getting more popular, I need to keep all files in the Android/data/com.companyName.MyApp_Q directory.

How do I intent from Q to P and give P the permissions to access the two files in Q's Android/data folder? I'm doing this in Xamarin, but I'll eventually have to recreate Q in straight Java once it's working.

Comment: You should use a file/content provider to serve your files.

Comment: You can also create a file in the public Documents directory and use SAF for the other app to let the user choose the file to rad/write.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is for Q to send a broadcast to P with URIs in the Intent (using ClipData). Q will grant persistable permission using [FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION) and [grantUriPermission()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#grantUriPermission(java.lang.String,%20android.net.Uri,%20int)). P will receive the broadcast with the URIs and accept them using [takePersistableUriPermission()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver#takePersistableUriPermission(android.net.Uri,%20int)). After that, P will be able to access the files using the URIs provided.
The URIs may come from FileProvider, so they are backed by the files in Q's external files directory.

Comment: What's the Xamarin equivalent to those methods, and how do I call them?